# jquery slidetoggle list without list elements trigger the effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am quite new to everything about html/js/css. Right now i need a list so i decided to use a list that u can slidetoggle. I looked it up and found how to recreate that effect (the code below):

```
        var subMenu = jQuery(".tableContainer ul li ul li");
        var linkClick = jQuery(".tableContainer ul li").filter(":has(ul)");

        linkClick.click(function () {
            $(this).find('ul li').slideToggle(200);
        });
```

(if you are wondering about the 2 ul and li, it is because i want that list in another list, but that doesn t change the question so i didn t include it in my explanation)
Since i am quite new to this topic, i only understand like 70% of what is happening. But for my project i need to work with the elements of the list(the ones which were hidden and after sliding down visible). I want to do stuff that requires clicking them like highlight on click, but now i encounter the problem, that the code i posted makes the slide effect being triggered not only by the headline, but also by the elements. So i cannot click elements without minimizing the list with the same click (obviously the elements are hidden again then). I hope you guys can explain me how to make the function only be triggered by the head object and not by the whole list element(head and the expanded list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look the slide effect is being triggered not only by the headline but also by the elements that are because the concept of event bubbling which basically means in case of click event if you clicked a child element the event is bubbled by default to the parent elements tree till the document level firing any registered event handler. so when you click the element you click the headline too, so you need to add another child element and handle the click on it something like this:-

```
 <div class="tableContainer">
    <ul>
     <li> <span>menu 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>link 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span> menu 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>link 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span> menu 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li>link 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <span>menu 4</span>
    <ul>
      <li>link 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


$(function() {
  var subMenu = jQuery(".tableContainer ul li ul li");
  var linkClick = jQuery(".tableContainer span");
  console.log(linkClick.length);

  linkClick.click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle(200);
  });
});
```

Full Working Example [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/k9OlX6b7NNGxXX3gomvO?p=preview)

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: if that helped you please up vote  and mark as answer. @LutzL